# Automatically convert recursion to iteration

Tags: loops, recursion

I have seen these questions:

- [Can and do compilers convert recursive logic to equivalent non-recursive logic?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202983/can-and-do-compilers-convert-recursive-logic-to-equivalent-non-recursive-logic)
- [Way to go from recursion to iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration)
- [Do any programming language compilers automatically convert recursion to iteration?](https://www.quora.com/Do-any-programming-language-compilers-automatically-convert-recursion-to-iteration)

These all mention tail-call optimization. I am wondering though if, given a function such as what follows, it is possible to automatically "flatten" it from recursive to iterative, using something other than tail-call optimization (which I don't think applies in this case, and I wouldn't want to place that restriction otherwise).

```
a() {
  while x < 3 {
    b()
  }
}

b() {
  c()
}

c() {
  d()
}

d() {
  a()
}
```

Notice `d` calls `a` and starts the recursion over, but assume that it won't recurse forever, just a few levels deep (this is just pseudocode). This is different than the fibonacci example which just has 1 function recursively calling itself. I'm wondering if any research has been done on the topic of automatically converting complex recursive functions like this into iterative ones.

Comment: If there is, students, including me, no need to struggle with homework anymore!

Comment: For a while babel would convert simple tail recursive functions to a while-loop. They've since [removed this feature](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/256) but [other examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-tailcall-optimization) exist. In short, yes a mechanical conversion is possible.